# in the street or on the street

Tags: prepositions

> He lives on Main Street.

This sentence is from "Merriam-Webster " Dictionary.

But I found both usage " in the street" and "on the street." on ngram.

What is the difference between them, "live on street" or "live in street".

Answer (score 3):

This is what one expects and where people usually live.

> live on the street
>   *live at an address of a particular street*
>   He lives on the street next to the town hall.

This is being homeless and sleeping rough

> live in the street
>   *living unsheltered, not in a house*
>   The dogs and cats of Rio live in the streets.

Comment: This may be a regional difference, but to this Northeastern US English speaker, someone who is homeless lives *on* the street, not *in* it.  *In* the street would literally mean "situated in the road".

Comment: Nope. 'The restaurant is tucked away in a side street.' (from here: https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/street)